# why FlutterError.onError not work before runApp()

Tags: flutter, onerror

I was testing flutter exception caught mechanism. when I coded like other internet example like this

```
void main() {
  FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    if (details.stack != null) {
      Zone.current.handleUncaughtError(details.exception, details.stack!);
    } else {
      FlutterError.presentError(details);
    }
  };
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

My onError function didn't run when i triggered a FlutterError. I traced the error function calling route and found it finally called system onError function which means my
custom onError function was ignored. I tried many ways to fix it , but all not working.

Finally i tried to change the order like this. Then my custom onError function work fine.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    if (details.stack != null) {
      Zone.current.handleUncaughtError(details.exception, details.stack!);
    } else {
      FlutterError.presentError(details);
    }
  };
}
```

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: Have you got any solution? @Zhu